# how to detect website link in Textview and make it clickable

Tags: android, database, hyperlink, textview

Guys I am trying to add large text with a website `link` like (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in my `textview` Located in database 
I tried adding it directly like this image :

picture of my value in databse

[image: picture of my value in databse]

But it appeared in the application on the form `Textview` not clickable like this image :

output app

[image: output app]

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // Parse les données JSON
        String id;
        String solution;
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                id= json_data.getString("alltext");
                solution = json_data.getString("title");
                prob.setText(solution);
                sol.setText(id);
                // Résultats de la requête
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 29):

Set the  `AutoLink` to `web` in `TextView` it will automatically detect the links

```
<TextView
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="This is Google http://www.google.com"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you  so much , please i have another question i want to make hyperlink like for example : (http://www.youtube.com) replace it by just Youtube

Comment: Use this code for hypelink text                                                   
 `TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); textView.setClickable(true); textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())‌​; String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>"; textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

First of All set the Text to TextView

```
lbl2.setText("hi http://google.com");
Linkify.addLinks(lbl2,Linkify.ALL);
```

Linkify automatically the clickable the link and other text remain same.

Comment: thanks so much , for help me :)

Comment: my pleasure :) mark up if its really help you.

Comment: thanks bro !!!@ArslanMaqbool

Comment: It's my pleasure @Divyaraj